# Google Apps Engine Dev Server Error

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm running Windows 7 64 and I get the following warnings when I run my project.  The file exists, and my path information seems to be correct.  Is this a known bug?

```
2012-04-25 22:19:51 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080', 'C:\\Users\\John\\workspace\\busilinks']"
WARNING  2012-04-25 15:19:53,253 datastore_file_stub.py:518] Could not read datastore data from c:\users\john\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.datastore
INFO     2012-04-25 15:19:53,299 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:647] Running application dev~busilinks on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-04-25 15:19:53,299 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:649] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
WARNING  2012-04-25 15:20:21,331 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg'
INFO     2012-04-25 15:20:21,766 datastore_stub_index.py:263] Updating C:\Users\John\workspace\busilinks\index.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its a know bug, since version 1.6.4 the data store file is not saved. more info at [issue 7244](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7244)

Comment: What about the warning about can't access setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg?